# Парсинг PHP кода в дерево

Tags: php, c#, парсер, дерево, antlr

Пишу интерпретатор PHP на C# (чисто для себя как open source). Застряла на парсинге выражений.

Что пробовала:

- Написала функцию через рекурсию, но криво обрабатывались ошибки синтаксиса, неправильно расставлялись приоритеты некоторым операторам и вообще код стал нереально громоздким и запутанным.
- Обратной польской записью, но этот способ рассчитан на то, что выражение изначально правильное, иначе дерево строится неправильно.

Подскажите, помогите найти или придумать способ парсинга именно выражения с проверкой синтаксиса.

На счёт готовых реализаций парсеров типа antlr и тп знаю, но не сильно вникала, хотелось бы с нуля пройти этот ад) Но можете писать идеи с их использованием в интерпретаторе (:

Репозиторий: [github.com/LoveNek0/PHPSharp](https://github.com/LoveNek0/PHPSharp)

Со всеми попытками реализации (на данный момент ОПЗ) можно ознакомится в истории коммитов.

Comment: дубликаты где-то [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=bison)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге удачный и лучший вариант, который мне удалось найти это **рекурсивный спуск**. Алгоритм достаточно прост, нужно просто понять принцип. Спасибо всем, кто не ответил (:
Норм статья, где это описано: https://habr.com/ru/articles/489534/